# How to override the hyperlink string value generated from XML in DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have a scenario where I need to change the name of the hyperlink in datagrid after checking a RadioButton that resides in separate “Options” window. I launch this “Option” Window using ICommand that assigned to the same hyperlink. I have trouble renaming the hyperlink name. The hyperlinks are generated from XML using XMLDataProvider. I also use IValueConverter that converts XML string to ICommand. I hope to find solution here. Thank you in advance.

Link to the testing solution:
http://cid-0c29483cf3a6a14d.office.live.com/self.aspx/WPF%5E_Tests/RenameHyperlinkText.zip

Code below.

Generating dataGrid with hyperlinks XAML in Main Window:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyStringToCommandConverter x:Key="MyStringToCommandConverter"/>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="MainDataGridLocal" XPath="ServicesTiles/Servers">
        <x:XData>
            <ServicesTiles xmlns="">
              <Servers Name="Name 1" Status="None" Name2="Name 2" Status2="Never" Command="LaunchOptionsWindowCommand" />
              <Servers Name="Name 3" Status="none"  Name2="Name 4" Status2="None" />
            </ServicesTiles>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
</Window.Resources> 
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainDataGridLocal}}">
    <DataGrid x:Name="MainGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/ServicesTiles/Servers}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=@Name}" />  
            <DataGridTemplateColumn >     
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>         
                    <DataTemplate>             
                        <TextBlock >
                            <Hyperlink Command="{Binding XPath=@Command, Converter={StaticResource MyStringToCommandConverter}}" >                
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Status}" />
                            </Hyperlink>
                        </TextBlock>         
                    </DataTemplate>     
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                          
            </DataGridTemplateColumn> 
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=@Status2}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn >     
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>         
                    <DataTemplate>             
                        <TextBlock >
                            <Hyperlink >                   
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Status2}" />
                            </Hyperlink>
                        </TextBlock>         
                    </DataTemplate>     
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                          
            </DataGridTemplateColumn> 
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Code behind to run command:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

public static RoutedUICommand OptionsWindowCommand = new RoutedUICommand("Options...", "Options", typeof(MainWindow));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(OptionsWindowCommand, OptionsWindowCommandExecuted));
    }
    private void OptionsWindowCommandExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OptionsWindow theDialog = new OptionsWindow();
        if ( theDialog != null )
            theDialog.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

OptionsWindow XAML with RadioButtons and OK button:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Height="250" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Content="Cancel" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,20,0" OpacityMask="#FFE0DADA" IsCancel="True" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="75"/>
    <Button Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Margin="0,0,103.06,0" IsDefault="True" />
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Width="158" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <RadioButton x:Name="a_RD" Content="1_RD" Height="25"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="b_RD" Content="2_RD;" IsChecked="True" Height="25"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="c_RD" Content="3_RD" Height="25"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I looked at your code and I'm not sure I understand what you want to do. After you've launched your Dialog, you select a value and then you want to change "the Name of the Hyperlink". Does this mean that you want to change the value of "Name" to something depending on what you selected in the Dialog? Is Name the one that's presented with `<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=@Name}" />`?

Comment: I'd like to change the string of the 'Status' node property to be 'Available' instead of 'None". Sorry for poor explanation. Please let me know if it is clear now.

Comment: And Yes, you understood it correctly. The change should happen when you select RadioButton and then click 'OK' button. Thank you again.

Comment: Updated my answer, is that close to what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understood your question but I took a stab at it anyway. You can use `CommandParameter` to send a parameter with the Command. If you use `CommandParameter="{Binding}"` you'll get the corresponding `XmlLinkedNode` for the clicked row (i.e. its `DataContext`) and from there you can access the attributes in it.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn >     
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>         
        <DataTemplate>             
            <TextBlock >
                <Hyperlink Command="{Binding XPath=@Command, Converter={StaticResource MyStringToCommandConverter}}"
                           CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Status}" />
                </Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>     
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                          
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Then you could do something like this in `OptionsWindowCommandExecuted`. I might add that I'm not that familiar working with `XmlDataProvider` so the `Attributes["Status"].Value` might not be the recommended way :)

```
private void OptionsWindowCommandExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OptionsWindow theDialog = new OptionsWindow();
    XmlLinkedNode xmlLinkedNode = e.Parameter as XmlLinkedNode;
    if (theDialog != null)
    {
        if (theDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            xmlLinkedNode.Attributes["Status"].Value = "Available";
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**
Some sample code to set different values depending on which `RadioButton` the user checked

**In OptionsWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public string CheckedRadioButtonContent
{
    get;
    set;
}

private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (a_RD.IsChecked == true)
    {
        CheckedRadioButtonContent = a_RD.Content.ToString();
    }
    else if (b_RD.IsChecked == true)
    {
        CheckedRadioButtonContent = b_RD.Content.ToString();
    }
    else if (c_RD.IsChecked == true)
    {
        CheckedRadioButtonContent = c_RD.Content.ToString();
    }
    DialogResult = true;
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void OptionsWindowCommandExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OptionsWindow theDialog = new OptionsWindow();
    XmlLinkedNode xmlLinkedNode = e.Parameter as XmlLinkedNode;
    if (theDialog != null)
    {
        if (theDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            string checkedRadioButtonContent = theDialog.CheckedRadioButtonContent;
            xmlLinkedNode.Attributes["Status"].Value = "Available_" + checkedRadioButtonContent;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have 3 radio buttons there. Is that possible to change the name based on which radio button was checked? Do you minfd to provide a sample code for it. Thank you again.

Comment: @vladc77: Added some sample code for this, was this what you meant?

Comment: Thank you! I have a problem. It is not renaming anymore.

Comment: Yes, I meant exactly what you added in the code. Unfortunatelly, it does not rename the attribute at all. I am looking for any error but cannot find it yet.

Comment: @vladc77: I uploaded my sample application. Compare it to yours to see the differences: http://www.mediafire.com/?v486v18lcxi2s49

Comment: I compared. In this sample, the attribute is not remaned either. Does it on your end? I am not sure what can be wrong. The code looks correct to me.

Comment: @vladc77: When I run it, click on a `Hyperlink` and press Ok in the Dialog, the value is changed in the DataGrid. Doesn't this happen for you?

Comment: I think you attached the initial solution.

Comment: @vladc77: Hehe, that wasn't my intention :) I'll check it out

Comment: @vladc77: I sure did... getting tired now :) I'll upload my version

Comment: Don't get tired. Get some fun. I highly appreciate your time. I am designer and just learning C#. You are genious with it.

Comment: @vladc77: Uploaded the correct version this time :) Give it another go: http://www.mediafire.com/?2dc40jx2nduzqcq

Comment: @vladc77: Didn't mean I was getting tired of you, I really am tired :) Will have to sleep soon before I fall asleep on the computer.